# jQuery this not selecting a single element

Tags: jquery, css

I have a few links with icons inside:

```
<div class="icons">
< href="..."><img src='' /></a>
< href="..."><img src='' /></a>
...
</div>
```

I'm trying to animate the `margin-top` css property of the `IMG`s using jQuery using the code:

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j("div.icons a").live({
mouseenter: 
function(){
    $j("img",this).animate({'margin-top': '-10px'}, 500);},
mouseleave:
function(){
    $j("img",this).animate({'margin-top': '-35px'}, 500);}
});
```

But it is changing the `margin-top` property of all images within DIV, not only the hovered one. What am I doing wrong?

You can see it working here:
http://pasterzdrzew.pl/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you used `display: inline-block;` on the links, you should use `display:block; float:left;` and that should do the trick (Tested using Chrome's Developer Tools).

Inline-block isn't entirely a block element and should be used very wisely as to prevent problems like this one with margins not behaving exactly like a block element.

Comment: Yep, it does! :) But still, I do not understand why would `inline-block` break this code?

Comment: Updated my answer with a little explanation.

Comment: @Gacek: You could have stuck with `display: inline-block` if you'd have added `vertical-align: top`. The default `vertical-align` is `baseline`, and adding `margin-top` to one of the elements adjusts the baseline downwards, so all the elements move.

Comment: Also, there's no need to add `display: block` when you have `float: left`.

Comment: I know you don't need to add it. I just like to explicitly write it so that anyone knows it's a block.